# TeXstudio quirks

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 2.11.0 on a Mac, and I like it a lot (this is not an attempt to convert anyone).

It has two bad attitudes though:

1) when I search with <kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd> sometimes it does not find the string that I searched for, so I have to close the search window, and restart it.

2) when I start to type `\cite` it nicely suggests a list of possible completions. But that list is not complete, and some citations (which are in my `.bib` file) do not show up at all.

Are there others who struggle with the same issues? If yes are there any fixes?

Thank you.

Comment: For (1), check if it is in case sensitive mode.